# Swap two key/value pairs in an array

Tags: php

I have an array:

```
$array = array('a' => 'val1', 'b' => 'val2', 'c' => 'val3', 'd' => 'val4');
```

How do I swap any two keys round so the array is in a different order?  E.g. to produce this array:

```
$array = array('d' => 'val4', 'b' => 'val2', 'c' => 'val3', 'a' => 'val1');
```

Thanks :).

Comment: In your sample code you're using an associative array. Key=>value order shouldn't matter in an associative array since the reason for an associative array is to access the values by their key and not their position in the array.

Comment: @DavidMyers: If you doing `foreach($array as $key=>$value)`, the order may matter.  For example: an HTML list or table.

Comment: @Rocket I agree that it could, but I would suggest that there are much better ways to organize the data. If it's coming from SQL then using ORDER BY. You can programmatically add information into the array based on order much easier than you can re-arrange if afterwards. That's assuming the array isn't hard-coded, in which case you should just write it in the order you want it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought there would be really simple answer by now, so I'll throw mine in the pile:

```
// Make sure the array pointer is at the beginning (just in case)
reset($array);

// Move the first element to the end, preserving the key
$array[key($array)] = array_shift($array);

// Go to the end
end($array);

// Go back one and get the key/value
$v = prev($array);
$k = key($array);

// Move the key/value to the first position (overwrites the existing index)
$array = array($k => $v) + $array;
```

This is swapping the first and last elements of the array, preserving keys. I thought you wanted `array_flip()` originally, so hopefully I've understood correctly.

Demo: http://codepad.org/eTok9WA6

Comment: My gut feeling is that you don't *really* need to do this, and there's another problem you want to solve, but you've picked this as the solution. Maybe I'm wrong, but I see that quite a bit here.

Comment: That's a neat solution.  Though, he may want to swap two arbitrary keys, not just the 1st and last.  +1 anyway because this is a cool solution.

Comment: He may want this if this array is being used for a HTML table for something, and the order matters.

Comment: @Rocket: Ah I see, I did misunderstand. Pretty weird question. As far as order in HTML output etc, there's plenty of ways to handle it in the display logic. Not sure what OP's specifically up against though..

Comment: I have no idea if that's what he's trying to do, but that's the only reason I could think of for why he'd want to do this.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Best</strike> A way is to make arrays of the keys and the values.  Swap the positions in both arrays, and  then put 'em back together.

```
function swapPos(&$arr, $pos1, $pos2){
  $keys = array_keys($arr);
  $vals = array_values($arr);
  $key1 = array_search($pos1, $keys);
  $key2 = array_search($pos2, $keys);

  $tmp = $keys[$key1];
  $keys[$key1] = $keys[$key2];
  $keys[$key2] = $tmp;

  $tmp = $vals[$key1];
  $vals[$key1] = $vals[$key2];
  $vals[$key2] = $tmp;

  $arr = array_combine($keys, $vals);
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/7gWKO

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal but does what you want to do:

```
$array = array('a' => 'val1', 'b' => 'val2', 'c' => 'val3', 'd' => 'val4');

$keys = array_keys($array);
swap($keys, 0, 3);
$values = array_values($array);
swap($values, 0, 3);
print_r(array_combine($keys, $values)); // Array ( [d] => val4 [b] => val2 [c] => val3 [a] => val1 )

function swap (&$arr, $e1, $e2)
{
    $temp = $arr[$e1];
    $arr[$e1] = $arr[$e2];
    $arr[$e2] = $temp;
}
```

Of course you should also check if both indexes are set in `swap` function (using `isset`)

Comment: You can use `array_search('a', $keys)` instead of using numeric keys.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just store the value to a variable for each?

```
$val1 = $array[0];
$val2 = $array[3];
$array[0] = $val2;
$array[3] = $val1;
```

Comment: He seems to want the order swapped, not the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to swap any value in array to any key .

```
/**
* switch value with value on key in given array
* array_switch( array( a, b ,c), c,0 );
* will return array(c, b, a);
*
*
* @param array $array            
* @param mixed $value            
* @param mixed $key            
* @return array
*/
public static function array_switch(&$array, $value, $key)
{
   // find the key of current value
   $old_key = array_search($value, $array);
   // store value on current key in tmep
   $tmp = $array[$key];
   // set values
   $array[$key] = $value;
   $array[$old_key] = $tmp;       
   return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old, but I needed this, and couldn't find anything satisfactory. So I rolled my own, and decided to share.

Using just one simple loop, this code is super readable to anyone.

I didn't benchmark, but I have a feeling it's not even that bad compared to the other `array_keys`, `array_values`, `array_combine` versions, even when going through a long array.

Should work for both numerical and string keys alike (only tested with string keys)

It's also easy to implement a check, if one or both keys not found and then throw error or return original array, or whatever you need

```
function arraySwap(array $array, $key1, $key2) {
    $value1 = $array[$key1];
    $value2 = $array[$key2];
    $newArray = [];
    foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
        if ($key === $key1) {
            $newArray[$key2] = $value2;
        } else if ($key === $key2) {
            $newArray[$key1] = $value1;
        } else {
            $newArray[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $newArray;
}
```